# 指定したカラム毎で最新のリストが欲しい(SQL, SELECT文)

Tags: mysql, sql

SQL文を教えて下さい。
user_id 毎の最新の bills 一覧を得る SELECT 文はどう書けば良いのでしょうか？

### テーブル定義

```
mysql> desc bills;
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                  | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id             | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_at          | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

### サンプル

```
+----+---------+------------+
| id | user_id | created_at |
+----+---------+------------+
|  1 |     111 | 2015-01-01 |
+----+---------+------------+
|  2 |     111 | 2015-01-02 |
+----+---------+------------+
|  3 |     111 | 2015-01-03 | ← 111 の中で最新の日付
+----+---------+------------+
|  4 |     222 | 2015-01-02 | ← 222 の中で最新の日付
+----+---------+------------+
|  5 |     222 | 2015-01-01 |
+----+---------+------------+
```

### 期待する結果

```
+----+---------+------------+
| id | user_id | created_at |
+----+---------+------------+
|  3 |     111 | 2015-01-03 |
+----+---------+------------+
|  4 |     222 | 2015-01-02 |
+----+---------+------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

既に回答は出されていますが、別の方法でやってみます。

```
SELECT * FROM bills AS b WHERE created_at = (
  SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM bills AS bs WHERE b.user_id = bs.user_id
);
```

この場合も最大値を持つレコードが複数ある場合は全て選択されることになります。

**追記**

最大値を持つレコードが複数ある場合に、例えば `id` が最も大きいレコードを抽出するには以下の様にします。

```
SELECT * FROM bills AS b WHERE id = (
  SELECT MAX(id) FROM bills AS bs
  WHERE b.user_id = bs.user_id AND
        created_at = (
          SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM bills AS bs
          WHERE b.user_id = bs.user_id)) ORDER BY user_id;
```

最小値の `id` を持つレコードを抽出する場合は、上記の `MAX(id)` を `MIN(id)` に変更します。

Answer (score 0):

結合し直してどの行が該当したのかを探すことでしょうか。

```
SELECT bills.*
FROM bills
INNER JOIN (SELECT user_id, MAX(created_at) AS created_at
            FROM bills
            GROUP BY user_id) AS max
ON bills.user_id = max.user_id AND bills.created_at = max.created_at
```

このクエリからわかりますが、あくまで`user_id`毎に`created_at`の最大値を選んだだけですので、最大値が複数行存在した場合は結果も複数になります。
それでは困るという場合は再度グループ化し、どのような`id`を選択するかを考える必要があります。

Answer (score 0):

id 列が不要ならば、以下のSQLで取得できます。

```sql
SELECT user_id, MAX(created_at) FROM bills GROUP BY user_id
```