# 最新時間のIDをユニークに抽出

Tags: sql

以下のようなテーブル構成の時、次の条件でデータを抽出したいです。

条件：timeが最新のglobal_idをユニークに抽出

※timeは被る場合もあります。
　global_idカラムの値が同じでidの値が違う場合も、同じ場合もあります。

・テーブル構成

```
table_name : mapping_table
time         |global_id |id       
---------------------------
1535338578   |7cbd0e54  |029abb9cd6e4
1535338577   |7cbd0e54  |0ab3cca02fc64
1535338577   |7cbd0e54  |ba12ec91b7664
1535338576   |e4bba841  |70b016d147eb4
```

↓

抽出したいレコード

```
time         |global_id |id       
---------------------------
1535338578   |7cbd0e54  |029abb9cd6e4
1535338576   |e4bba841  |70b016d147eb4
```

Comment: 過去に同様の質問があります。
こちらで解決できませんか？
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/16616/%E6%8C%87%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%82%AB%E3%83%A9%E3%83%A0%E6%AF%8E%E3%81%A7%E6%9C%80%E6%96%B0%E3%81%AE%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%81%8C%E6%AC%B2%E3%81%97%E3%81%84sql-select%E6%96%87

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決できそうです。